# Using runif in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to use `runif` for the following data set :

```
   LB   UB   N
   500  600  20
   600  700  30
   700  800  1234
   ...
```

Have converted the columns to vectors:

```
  c1<- as.list(d2[,c("N")])
  min=seq(500,2800,100)
  min=as.vector(min)
  max=seq(600,2900,100)
  max=as.vector(max)
```

Looping through:

```
for(i in seq(1,3,1)) 
 {
  p<- runif(c1[[i]],min=min[[i]],max=max[[i]])
 }
```

I need the `n`, `min` & `max` to be chosen dynamically from the data itself.
Can someone help?

Comment: `min` and `max`are functions. Using other variable names might be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking directly to the data frame containing your bounds and sample number (in this example just using the 3 rows you've given above):

```
df <- read.table(text = 'LB   UB   N
                         500  600  20
                         600  700  30
                         700  800  1234',
                 header = TRUE)

p <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  p[[i]] <- runif(df$N[i], min = df$LB[i], max = df$UB[i])
}

str(p)
# List of 3
# $ : num [1:20] 506 578 526 566 522 ...
# $ : num [1:30] 674 681 648 614 615 ...
# $ : num [1:1234] 782 744 746 744 784 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Map` to iterate through the data frame:

```
with(df, Map(runif, N, LB, UB))
#List of 3
# $ : num [1:20] 573 543 552 535 571 ...
# $ : num [1:30] 691 655 642 640 695 ...
# $ : num [1:1234] 703 739 705 705 759 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also go for `apply`:

```
set.seed(123)
l <- apply(df,1,function(x) runif(x[3],min=x[1],max=x[2]))
```

Or using `by`:

```
l <- by(df,1:nrow(df),function(x) runif(x$N,min=x$LB,max=x$UB))

#lapply(l,head)

# [[1]]
# [1] 528.7578 578.8305 540.8977 588.3017 594.0467 504.5556 ...

# [[2]]
# [1] 688.9539 669.2803 664.0507 699.4270 665.5706 670.8530 ...

# [[3]]
# [1] 704.5831 744.2200 779.8925 712.1899 756.0948 720.6531 ...
```

Comment: All the codes work fine when I read the data as a table but the moment its read as a csv the code tend to throw an error:  Error in runif(c1$X27.Jun_new[i], min = c1$LB[i], max = c1$UB[i]) : 
  invalid arguments

Comment: @user6016731 you need to fetch your data from `csv` file to a data frame or table properly. Nothing is mentioned that this code will work for all type of data, all type of objects, etc!